# Docker Container not connecting with host mariaDB

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb, telnet

I have MariaDB running on my host machine. This MariaDB is accessible from systems and Docker containers running from other host but not accessible from a Docker container running on this host. I also try to telnet on port 3306 is successful from containers running on other host but fail when trying from the container on the same host.

Comment: Are you using IP address or hostname to connect with the mariaDB on the host?

Comment: Add more detail command instead of just description.

Answer (score -1):

do a docker inspect and check if both the containers are on the same network.
Under Networks , you can check the network name

Comment: The question sounds a lot like the database isn't running in Docker.  It's also not clear how running `docker inspect` on its own would solve the problem.

Comment: database is running in host and and connecting from other servers but from docker container running in that host

Comment: docker inspect give the details of the container ,  do a "docker inspect "container_name"" and check the the network name under all the containers. Make sure that the network name is same under all containers